# Is there a Python typing class that means "set, list, or tuple"-like thing?

Tags: python, collections, type-hinting

Is there a Python `typing` class for a collection of items that is *not* a mapping -- i.e., a set, list, or tuple, but not a dict? I.e., does this `Unicorn` exist?

```
>>> from typing import Unicorn
>>> isinstance({1, 2, 3}, Unicorn)
True
>>> isinstance([1, 2, 3], Unicorn) 
True
>>> isinstance((1, 2, 3), Unicorn)
True
>>> isinstance({1: 'a', 2: 'b'}, Unicorn)
False
```

`Collection` sure looked promising but dicts are `Collection`s too.

Comment: typing has `List`, `Tuple`, `Set`, `Dict`, and more.

Comment: The type you're asking for doesn't make a lot of sense. There are 3 operations supported by `set`, `list`, and `tuple`: `in`, `iter`, and `len`. Dicts support all 3 of those operations too, and the relationship between `in`, `iter`, and `len` for dicts is exactly the same as the relationship between those operations for sets, lists and tuples.

Comment: Plus, it would break subtype transitivity. A non-mapping collection class can have a subclass that *is* a mapping.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - Interesting point. Could you give an example where that would make sense?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica - I'm trying to write a library of collection methods. Some make intuitive sense on non-mapping collections but not really on maps. Take `sort_by()` -- on a dict, is that sorting by key or value? Beats me. So I'm looking for a way to distinguish collection types where my methods make sense, i.e. there's no ambiguity about what's going on, vs. maps, where it's confusing. (For the map I probably want to separately define a `sort_by_key()` and `sort_by_value()`.)

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use:

```
from typing import List, Tuple, Set, Union


def test(x):
    print(isinstance(x, (List, Tuple, Set)))


def typed_f(x: Union[List, Tuple, Set]):
    print(x)


test({1, 2, 3})
test([1, 2, 3])
test((1, 2, 3))
test({1: 'a', 2: 'b'})
```

Result:

```
True
True
True
False
```

And the typing of `typed_f` is typical usage, so this would get you a warning in a good IDE:

```
typed_f({1: 'a', 2: 'b'})
```

Comment: This is my current goto. However, I was hoping to find a type that was more general -- for instance, maybe I want numpy arrays to work. I'd prefer not to have to exhaustively list all the types; just use something that means "any non-mapping collection".

Comment: There's no 'set of iterable types' you could subtract the 'mapping types' from - that's taking it too far. The problem here is you want to allow `Any` iterable, except some specific ones for some reason (even though others have pointed out that these reasons may be misguided). After all, why disallow a mapping, as that's also an iterable? If you have some specific reason not to want to allow mapping, you probably should check for that specific condition in the function, but you can't get the type checkers to follow those rules.

Answer (score 2):

No, not that I know of.

This helper function I wrote a while ago may help you though, depending on what your goal is;

```
def is_iterable(item):
    return hasattr(item, "__iter__") and not isinstance(item, dict)
```

You can easily add further exceptions in the isinstance call if required.

Comment: This definitely works at runtime, but doesn't help me with the type hint, so I can't use a static type checker like `pyright`. I wonder if there's some way to define a user-defined type negatively (`Not[Mapping]`)? I'm not seeing this.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry but that's out of my scope, having never bothered with type hinting myself. Good luck :)

Comment: and `and not isinstance(item, str)` :(

Comment: @nezda yeah, assuming you don't want strings. Just remember that isinstance can take an iterable as the second argument though. Personally I'd probably find `not isinstance(item, (dict, str))` neater.